# How can this NullReferenceException happen?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, mscorlib

I'm investigation the following NRE:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey key)
at UC4.Decision.Core.Event.EventObjectHeader.get_Item(String key)
...
```

My `EventObjectHeader` class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Threading;
using UC4.Common.Utils.Xml;

namespace UC4.Decision.Core.Event
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enumeration of the event priority.
    /// </summary>
    public enum EventPriority
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Event Priority Low
        /// </summary>
        Low = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// Event Priority Medium (Default)
        /// </summary>
        Medium = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// Event Priority High
        /// </summary>
        High = 2,
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Structure for the header information of an event object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="EventObject"/>
    [Serializable]
    public class EventObjectHeader : IEventObjectHeader, ISerializable
    {
        public const string KEY_TYPEURI = "typeUri";

        /// <summary>
        /// Fixed key which is used to store the predefined header element GUID.
        /// </summary>
        public const string KEY_GUID = "guid";

        /// <summary>
        /// Fixed key which is used to store the predefined header element IsPersistent.
        /// </summary>
        public const string KEY_ISPERSISTENT = "isPersistent";

        /// <summary>
        /// Fixed key which is used to store the time created in eventbase timezone of the Event.
        /// </summary>
        public const string KEY_TIME_CREATED = "timeCreated";


        /// <summary>
        /// Fixed key which is used to store the time created in UTC timezone of the Event.
        /// </summary>
        public const string KEY_TIME_CREATED_UTC = "timeCreatedUTC";

        /// <summary>
        /// Fixed key which is used to store the predefined header element Priority.
        /// </summary>
        public const string KEY_PRIORITY = "priority";

        // internal data structure to store header elements as string tuples
        private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _internal = new Dictionary<string, string>(6);

        // lock for read and write requests to the internal dictionary
        private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _internalDictionaryLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        // caching dictionary
        protected readonly Hashtable _cachedHeaderAttributes = Hashtable.Synchronized(new Hashtable());

        /// <summary>
        /// default header attributes (always loaded because they are columns of EB_EVENTS)
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly ICollection<String> DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTES = new List<string>(new[]
                                                                           {
                                                                               KEY_GUID, KEY_TIME_CREATED, 
                                                                               KEY_TIME_CREATED_UTC,KEY_TYPEURI
                                                                           });

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EventObjectHeader"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public EventObjectHeader()
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether the event is persistent
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPersistent
        {
            get
            {
                if (ContainsKey(KEY_ISPERSISTENT) == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return GetValueAs<bool>(KEY_ISPERSISTENT);
            }
            set { SetValue(KEY_ISPERSISTENT, value); }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EventObjectHeader"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="eventObjectHeaderToCopy">The event object header to copy.</param>
        private EventObjectHeader(IEventObjectHeader eventObjectHeaderToCopy) : this()
        {
            List<String> keys = new List<string>(eventObjectHeaderToCopy.Keys);
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                Add(key, eventObjectHeaderToCopy[key]);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property for accessing the predefined header element GUID.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual Guid Guid
        {
            get
            {
                if (ContainsKey(KEY_GUID) == false)
                {
                    return Guid.Empty;
                }
                return GetValueAs<Guid>(KEY_GUID);
            }
            set { SetValue(KEY_GUID, value); }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Property for accessing the predefined header element LocalTimeCreated.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual DateTime TimeCreated
        {
            get
            {
                if (ContainsKey(KEY_TIME_CREATED) == false)
                {
                    return default(DateTime);
                }
                return GetValueAs<DateTime>(KEY_TIME_CREATED);
            }
            set { SetValue(KEY_TIME_CREATED, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property for accessing the predefined header element UTC Time created
        /// </summary>
        public virtual DateTime TimeCreatedUTC
        {
            get
            {
                if (ContainsKey(KEY_TIME_CREATED_UTC) == false)
                {
                    return default(DateTime);
                }
                return GetValueAs<DateTime>(KEY_TIME_CREATED_UTC);
            }
            set { SetValue(KEY_TIME_CREATED_UTC, value); }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Property for accessing the predefined header element Priority.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual EventPriority Priority
        {
            get
            {
                if (ContainsKey(KEY_PRIORITY) == false)
                {
                    return EventObjectHeaderHelper.DEFAULT_PRIORITY;
                }
                return GetValueAs<EventPriority>(KEY_PRIORITY);
            }
            set { SetValue(KEY_PRIORITY, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Make a copy of the event object header instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>New instance with the same values</returns>
        public virtual EventObjectHeader Copy()
        {
            return new EventObjectHeader(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clear the event object header.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Clear()
        {
            _internalDictionaryLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                _internal.Clear();
                _cachedHeaderAttributes.Clear();
            }
            finally
            {
                _internalDictionaryLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Access the stored values via the key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Attribute key</param>
        /// <returns>Value</returns>
        public virtual string this[string key]
        {
            set
            {
                _internalDictionaryLock.EnterWriteLock();
                try
                {
                    _internal[key] = value;
                    if (_cachedHeaderAttributes.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        _cachedHeaderAttributes.Remove(key);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _internalDictionaryLock.ExitWriteLock();    
                }
            }
            get
            {
                _internalDictionaryLock.EnterReadLock();
                try
                {
                    if (_internal.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        return _internal[key];
                    }    
                }
                finally
                {
                    _internalDictionaryLock.ExitReadLock();
                }
                if (key == KEY_ISPERSISTENT)
                {
                    // this is to prevent a Exception when the IsPersistent attribute
                    // hadn't been set in advance
                    return XmlHelper.XmlConvertValueToString(false);
                }
                throw new EventObjectException(1167, key);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove a stored value by its key.
        /// If the key was not found, <code>null</code> is returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Attribute key</param>
        /// <returns>The value of the element which was removed</returns>
        public virtual string Remove(string key)
        {
            string retVal;
            _internalDictionaryLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                _internal.TryGetValue(key, out retVal);
                _internal.Remove(key);
                if (_cachedHeaderAttributes.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    _cachedHeaderAttributes.Remove(key);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _internalDictionaryLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a collection of the stored keys inside the header.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<string> Keys
        {
            get
            { 
                _internalDictionaryLock.EnterReadLock();
                try
                {
                     return _internal.Keys;
                }
                finally
                {
                    _internalDictionaryLock.ExitReadLock();
                }                
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if the header contains a specific element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Attribute key</param>
        /// <returns>true, if the header contains a value for this key</returns>
        public virtual bool ContainsKey(string key)
        {
            _internalDictionaryLock.EnterReadLock();
            bool retVal;
            try
            {
                retVal = _internal.ContainsKey(key);    
            }
            finally
            {
                _internalDictionaryLock.ExitReadLock();    
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Read only property which counts the elements in the header.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int Count
        {
            get
            {
                _internalDictionaryLock.EnterReadLock();
                int retVal;
                try
                {
                    retVal = _internal.Count;
                }
                finally
                {
                    _internalDictionaryLock.ExitReadLock();
                }
                return retVal;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a stored element casted to a specific type.
        /// if the value is not found, the default of this type is returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Runtime type of the value</typeparam>
        /// <param name="key">Attribute key</param>
        /// <returns>RuntimeType safe value</returns>
        public virtual T GetValueAs<T>(String key)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_cachedHeaderAttributes.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    Object obj = _cachedHeaderAttributes[key];
                    if (obj is T)
                    {
                        return (T) obj;
                    }
                }
                String value = this[key];
                return XmlHelper.XmlConvertStringToValue<T>(value);
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException e)
            {
                throw e.InnerException;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a new element with a specific key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Attribute key</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value</param>
        public virtual void Add(String key, String value)
        {
            Add(key, value, false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a new element with a specific key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Optional runtime type parameter</typeparam>
        /// <param name="key">Attribute key</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value</param>
        public virtual void Add<T>(String key, T value)
        {
            Add(key, value, false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a value for a specific key.
        /// If the key was already used, the value is overwritten and the old one is returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Optional runtime type parameter</typeparam>
        /// <param name="key">Attribute key</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value</param>
        /// <returns>The old value if it exists</returns>
        public virtual string SetValue<T>(String key, T value)
        {
            string retVal = null;
            _internalDictionaryLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                if (_internal.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    retVal = _internal[key];
                }    
                _internal.Remove(key);
                _internal.Add(key, XmlHelper.XmlConvertValueToString(value));
                _cachedHeaderAttributes[key] = value;
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException e)
            {
                throw e.InnerException;
            }
            finally
            {
                _internalDictionaryLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
            return retVal;
        }


        // generic add value to the header
        protected virtual void Add<T>(String key, T value, bool overwrite)
        {
            _internalDictionaryLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                if (overwrite)
                {
                    _internal.Remove(key);
                }
                _internal.Add(key, XmlHelper.XmlConvertValueToString(value));
                _cachedHeaderAttributes[key] = value;
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException e)
            {
                throw e.InnerException;
            }
            finally
            {
                _internalDictionaryLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        #region ISerializable Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance from the serialization stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info">Serializer information</param>
        /// <param name="context">Serialization stream context</param>
        protected EventObjectHeader(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            _internal =
                info.GetValue("headerAttributes", typeof (Dictionary<string, string>)) as Dictionary<string, string>;
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("headerAttributes", _internal);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

All access to the `_internal` dictionary is protected by a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` - thus I can't see any possible concurrency issue.

With dotPeek I digged into the `Dictionary` class. Its `ContainsKey` method just returns `this.FindEntry(key) >= 0`, the `FindEntry` method looks like this:

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key)
{
  if ((object) key == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
  if (this.buckets != null)
  {
    int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & int.MaxValue;
    for (int index = this.buckets[num % this.buckets.Length]; index >= 0; index = this.entries[index].next)
    {
      if (this.entries[index].hashCode == num && this.comparer.Equals(this.entries[index].key, key))
        return index;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

And the `GenericEqualityComparer`'s `GetHashCode` method looks like that:

```
public override int GetHashCode(T obj)
{
  if ((object) obj == null)
    return 0;
  else
    return obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

In the end, all I'm doing is a simple `ContainsKey` on a `Dictionary<string, string>`. I have no explanation for the NRE, but it seems to happen regularly in one of our customer's productive system. What could possibly explain the NullReferenceException?

Comment: Use the debugger to verify `_internal = info.GetValue(...)`

Comment: Good point, I could imagine that something funny is happening during serialization/deserialization. However (1) it doesn't look like that this object is deserialized and more importantly (2) according to the stack trace, it's all usual .Net classes (not some artificial proxies or the like) and the exception happens before we even look at the content of the dictionary itself. Or am I missing something there?